# Consolidate Weekly Excel Worksheet Into One Master Workbook

Tags: excel, merge

I am trying to combine over Excel 31 worksheets of data with identical headers into one.  There are too many rows for the power query to handle.  I tried VBA, but I'm not proficient in it, so that didn't work.  This is a workbook that will be added to on a weekly bases.

I am trying to combine 31 worksheets on a centralized file into a master sheet. It will be updated with new data on a weekly bases.  The headers are identical on each workbook.  There is too much data for the power query to handle. The goal is to be able to add data to a master data source and refresh pivot tabs for the functioning dashboard.

Comment: It really seems like you're (ab)using Excel as a database.

Comment: Yes, I do not know what else to do.

Comment: Can you create an actual database?

Comment: I am not sure how to build one in access.